# Searching Cells & Extracting Rows

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to examine on which rows a particular value is located in a cell, then retrieve the rows in those positions from another cell and put them into a variable.

My data is like:

```
1x4 Cell =

     A           B          C            D           %Cell labels for clarity
{10x1 Cell} {10x1 Cell} {10x1 Cell} [10x1 Double]

   B          blue          M           4.78
   R          red           N           6.43
   R          red           N           6.89
   B          blue          M           7.99
   B          blue          M           5.87
   B          blue          M           4.78
   R          red           N           6.43
   R          red           N           6.89
   B          blue          M           7.99
   B          blue          M           5.87
```

So for example, it would go like this: 1) search for the rows on which `"blue"` is located in `B`, 2) "blue" is found to be in rows 1, 4, 5, 6, 9 and 10. Then 3) extract rows 1, 4, 5, 6, 9 and 10 from another datacell, `C`, to a new variable.

As far as I am aware, logic operations like `==` may not be sufficient for what I want to do. Which functions should I be looking at to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you define `A` to be a cell if it is a matrix? or maybe I didn't understand you. What do the cells `A`,`B`,... contain?

Comment: Is `A` a cell array that contains cells? are entries of A mixed (that is strings and doubles)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
C(cellfun(@isequal, B, repmat({'blue'},10,1)))
```

Explanation:

- `repmat` makes a cellarray of 'blue' with a size of B
- `isequal` compares the content of two cells
- `cellfun` repeats for all cells and returns logical column
- `C(...)` indexes C with this column and returns matching rows

Regards

Answer (score 2):

I would do it in two steps. First do the comparison and get the logical array and then use that and cell fun to extract your rows.

```
idx = strcmp('blue', A{2});
B = cellfun(@(x) x(idx), A, 'UniformOutput', false);
```